# Spring AOP in different projects does not work

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP and AspectJ but the simplicity they can provide makes me want to use them.

The questions is: I have two projects, one is a spring boot application `server` and the other one contains all the utilities functions `core`. I want to implement logging aspect in both projects and here is what I did:

**server**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MethodLoggingAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(logExecutionTime)")
    public Object methodLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogExecutionTime logExecutionTime) throws Throwable {
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        final long start = System.nanoTime();

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

        final long end = System.nanoTime();

        logger.info("method={}, millis={}", joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start));
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class BeanConfiguration {
}
```

**core**

```java
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}
```

I use the annotation `LogExecutionTime` both in `core` and application `server` these are two different jars and `server` has dependency `core`. I expect the aspect will work in both two parts when I run `server`, but the fact is that only methods in `server` have the aspect weaved in.

I also tried to define the aspect in `core` and use aspectJ to do compile-time weaving. But there is Immutable library in `core`, which will throw a compile time error when I use `aspectj-maven-plugin`.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions here and what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then update your question so as to enable us to reproduce and analyse your problem instead of making wild guesses based on your plain prose. Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex, thank you very much! I just edited it, and hopefully it provides more detail to my question.

Comment: Before you try anything else: You should not instantiate the aspect as a bean, just let Spring take care of its life cycle, remove the `@Bean` method and add a `@ComponentScan` annotation to your config class. If that does not help, we can still try something else.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you and sorry for the late response. I tried this way, but it is still the same. Only works in one part.